# C++ Array error with certain inputs

Tags: c++, arrays

So in this program, when the user enters, for example, "shirt", for the name of a sales item, it skips right to the output and fails.  However, if I enter a simple number such as just a 10 for the name of the sales item, everything runs just fine.  Any help would be appreciated

edit: the function was pulled out of a larger program to post.  In the main program, it is a float function, not an int and still gives the error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double taxPct;
char status;
double saleAmount, value;

do
{
    system("cls");  // clears the screen when the user runs the program again
    saleAmount = 0; // resets sale amount to 0 when the user runs the program again

    cout
    <<"********************************************" <<endl
    <<"********************************************" <<endl
    <<"*****" << right << setw(39) << "*****" <<endl
    <<"*****" << setw(24) << "W E L C O M E" << setw(15) << "*****" <<endl
    <<"*****" << setw(39) << "*****" <<endl
    <<"*****" << setw(23) << "T O   T H E" <<setw(16) << "*****" <<endl
    <<"*****" << setw(39) << "*****" <<endl
    <<"*****" << setw(30) << "S A L E S   R E C E I P T" <<setw(9) << "*****" <<endl
    <<"*****" << setw(39) << "*****" <<endl
    <<"*****" << setw(24) << "P R O G R A M" <<setw(15) << "*****" <<endl
    <<"*****" << setw(39) << "*****" <<endl
    <<"********************************************" <<endl
    <<"********************************************" <<endl
    <<endl;

    int items;
    cout << "How many sales items do you have? : ";
    cin >> items;

    int sales[items][2];
    int counter =0;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < items; counter++)
        {
            cout << "Enter the name of sales item " << counter + 1 << ": ";
            cin >> sales[counter][0];

            cout << "Enter the price of " << sales[counter][0] << " : $";
            cin >> sales[counter][1];

            saleAmount=saleAmount+sales[counter][1];
        }

    cout << "Enter in the sales tax percentage" <<endl
         << "(Enter 10 for 10%): ";
    cin >> taxPct;
    cout <<endl <<endl;

    if (taxPct>.9999)
    {                        // failsafe: converts tax percentage to a decimal for calculating tax amount if a whole number is entered (i.e. entering .06 or 6 will give the same result)
        taxPct=taxPct/100;
    }

    double taxAmount = saleAmount * taxPct;
    double grandTotal = saleAmount + taxAmount;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2)

    <<"********************************************" <<endl
    <<"********" << setw(26) << "S A L E S  R E C E I P T" << setw(10) << "********" <<endl
    <<"********************************************" <<endl
    <<"**" << setw(42) << "**" <<endl
    <<"**" << setw(42) << "**" <<endl
    <<"**  Item" << setw(26) << "Price" << setw(10) << "**" <<endl
    <<"**  ------------------------------------  **" <<endl;

    for (counter = 0; counter < items; counter++)
    {

    cout <<"**  " << left << setw(12) << sales[counter][0] << right << setw(11) << "$" << setw(9) << sales[counter][1] << setw(8) << "**" <<endl;

    }

    cout
    <<"**" << setw(42) << "**" <<endl
    <<"**" << setw(42) << "**" <<endl
    <<"********************************************" <<endl
    <<"**" << setw(42) << "**" <<endl
    <<"**" << setw(42) << "**" <<endl
    << left << setw(4) << "**" << setw(11) << "Total Sales" << right <<setw(12) << "$" << setw(9) << saleAmount << setw(8) <<"**" <<endl
    << left << setw(4) << "**" << setw(9) << "Sales Tax" << right <<setw(14) << "$" << setw(9) << taxAmount << setw(8) <<"**" <<endl
    << left << setw(27) << "**" << setw (15) << "-----------" <<"**" <<endl
    << left << setw(4) << "**" << setw(11) << "Grand Total" << right << setw(12)<< "$" << setw(9) << grandTotal << setw(8) <<"**" <<endl
    <<"**" << setw(42) << "**" <<endl
    <<"**" << setw(42) << "**" <<endl
    <<"********************************************" <<endl <<endl <<endl;

    cout <<"Do you want to run this program again? (Y/N): "; // asks user if they wish to calculate another sale
    cin >> status;
    cout <<endl;

}
while (status == 'Y' || status == 'y');

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to store character data into an `int`.

Comment: Right.  I am already aware that that is the issue, looking for where I went wrong in the code.  Thanks

Comment: Not using a type that allows you to enter both numeric and alphanumeric strings is where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you need to design your data structures. You seem to want to store sales information and you have 2 things for each item, name and price. So lets make a sales item

```
struct SalesItem
{
std::string Name;
int Price; // maybe there is a better type, but int will do
}
```

now lets allocate some

```
SalesItem sitems[items];
```

ok now lets input one

```
    cout << "Enter the name of sales item " << counter + 1 << ": ";
    cin >> sitems[counter].Name;

    cout << "Enter the price of " << sitems[counter].Name << " : $";
    cin >> sitems[counter].Price;
```

you should consider std::vector instead of an array.

You should use a type designed to hold money (google c++ money type)